# Assigning a class to a variable

Tags: python, class, oop, object

```
class SimpleTestCase(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.SP = SP

    def __somemethod(self):
     # do something

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name ):
        self.name = name
        self.case = SimpleWidgetTestCase
```

Is there any reason to do

```
self.case = SimpleTestCase
```

instead of

```
simple_obj = SimpleTestCase("name")
```

By creating object one can access the class methods and variables. Is the former equivalent to latter?

Comment: It's not at all clear how you think `simple_obj = SimpleTestCase()` could possibly replace `self.case = SimpleWidgetTestCase`. Classes in Python, like pretty much everything else, are first-class objects, to they can be passed around and assigned to names/attributes like anything else.

Comment: they are not equivelent ... sometimes a class may need certain conditions to be present to be instanciated, which may not be present until later in the programs execution

Comment: You defined an `__init__` that accept a parameter but you didn't give any when calling `SimpleTestCase()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason to do
>   `self.case = SimpleTestCase`

Yes there is a reason. Some times one would like to store a type without creating an instance.
Creating an instance can be expensive, if for example the `__init__` does things like opening database connections, reading large files, etc.

> By creating object one can access the class methods and variables. Is the former equivalent to latter?

No, the former is not equal to the latter.
In the former you assign a type to a variable. In the latter you asign an instance.
Python allows you to access methos and variables if they are class methods  (or static methods) or class variables. This way you don't need to create and instance. 
By creating an Instance, you are accessing the instance methods.

See this link about [difference between staticmethod and classmethod in python](http://pythoncentral.io/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python/)

Comment: This makes sense. It can be used to call class variable and static methods. Thanks!!